# There are several circles of total length $10$ inside square of side $1$ . Show that there exists a straight line which intersects atleast $4$ circles

Tags: geometry

> There are several circles of total length $10$ inside a square of side $1$. Show that there exists a straight line which intersects atleast $4$ circles.

The solution given in *Problem Solving Strategies* by Arthur Engel is as follows:

> Orthogonally project all circles onto side $AB$ of a unit square. A circle of length $l$ will project onto a segment of length $l/\pi$. The sum of the projections of all circles is $10/\pi$. Since $10/\pi>3=3AB$,there is a point on $AB$ belonging to the projections of at least four circles. The perpendicular to $AB$ through this point intersects at least four circles.
>
> > However, I didn't get the idea of the solution. I don't know what is meant by orthogonal projection and how they find the sum of all orthogonal projections...

Comment: Visibly you have many questions (four of them in a very short amount of time) about the same book. Are you self studying or do you have an instructor ? In the first case, look maybe for a simpler book.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: $10$ intervals $I_k=[a_k,b_k]\subset[0,1]$ (the "shadows" of the diameters of the circles with a sun at infinity) with lengths $L(I_k)=b_k-a_k$ such that
$$\underbrace{\sum_k L(I_k)}_S>3 \tag{1}$$

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\sum \chi_k(x)$$

obtained by summing all the characteristic (or indicator) functions of intervals $I_k$ (the characteristic function $\chi$ of an interval $[a,b]$ is defined by $\chi(x)=1$ if $x \in [a,b]$, otherwise $\chi(x)=0$).

Please note that fuction $f$ is called a ["step function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) with a graphical representation looking like a "skyscraper line" with integer heights ( = values).

[image]

(1) can be transformed into

$$S=\int_0^1 f(x)dx > 3$$

which is possible if and only if the "skyscraper line" is situated for certain values of $x$ above line $y=3$ (in green), any of these values being solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the orthogonal projection as the shadow of the circle on the bottom side if it was illuminated from the top. The size of the shadow will be equal to the diameter of the circle. If a circle have a diameter $D$, then its length is $l = D\pi$, so $D = \frac{l}{\pi}$. If we sum on all circles, because the sum of the lengths is $10$, the total length will be $\frac{10}{\pi}$